# error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘unsigned int’ using type ‘sfVector2f

Tags: c, sfml

i need to code a game with CSFML lib, i'am trying to follow guide in SFML and i get an error.

error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘unsigned int’ using type ‘sfVector2f {aka struct}’
     sfVector2u size = {sfSprite_getScale(sprite)};

```
#include "include/game_include.h"
int main()
{
sfVideoMode mode = {800, 600, 32};
sfRenderWindow* window;
sfTexture* texture;
sfSprite* sprite;
sfVector2u size = {sfSprite_getScale(sprite));
sfVector2f origin = {};
sfEvent event;
window = sfRenderWindow_create(mode, "SFML window", sfResize | sfClose, NULL);
if (!window)
    return 1;
texture = sfTexture_createFromFile("img.jpg", NULL);
if (!texture)
    return 1;
sprite = sfSprite_create();
sfSprite_setTexture(sprite, texture, sfTrue);
sfSprite_setOrigin(sprite, origin);
while (sfRenderWindow_isOpen(window))
{
    while (sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(window, &event))
    {
        if (event.type == sfEvtClosed)
            sfRenderWindow_close(window);
    }
    sfRenderWindow_clear(window, sfBlack);
    sfRenderWindow_drawSprite(window, sprite, NULL);
    sfRenderWindow_display(window);
}
sfRenderWindow_destroy(window);
sfSprite_destroy(sprite);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: If there are two types something2u and something2f, then I bet that 2f is a float and inappropriate to init any int.

Comment: Please review your question. Is it formatted as you want it? Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Does your code provide a [mcve]? Did you make clear enough where exactly the mentioned error occurs? I.e. did you label that line with a comment "error" here? Did you quote the error message in full and verbatim? I think the answers to these questions are: no, no, no, no and no.

Comment: OT You're passing an uninitialised pointer `sprite` to `sfSprite_getScale`.  That will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: can someone help me to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Just move the line where you get the scale **after** the line where you initialize the sprite with `sfSprite_create()`. Then, the `sfSprite_getScale()` returns a `sfVector2f` so if you want to store it in a `sfVector2u`, cast each part of the vector with `(unsigned)` (and an intermediate variable) but you did not use the `sfSprite_setScale()`.

Else, the rest of your code seems ok to display the sprite